# how to list all current access in Linux server

Tags: linux, command, redhat

I have 2 Redhat servers, one is Application server and another is DB server.
I need to check whether the request from Application server can reach DB server or not? I have tried #who -u but it shows only user login.

How to list up request which reached DB server?

Best regards,
Wuttisak Thabthimsaen

Comment: What kind of request? What kind of DB?

Comment: Hi sideshowbarker,
Request to insert 1 record into ORACLE DB by calling JDBC in WAS.